# Why does Winston output `undefined` with custom format?

Tags: node.js, winston

```
let logger = winston.createLogger({
     format: {
         transform(info, opts) {
             info.message = "!" + info.message + "!";
             return info;
         }
    },
    transports: [
         new winston.transports.Console()
     ]
});
logger.info("Something");
```

This code outputs "undefined" in my console. Why? If I use the default formats, it works perfectly. But if I use my own or even custom formats from official winston examples, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's different for each version

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: winston.format.printf(info => `!${info.message}!`)
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. as [KiDoo Song](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62277990/4469928) has mentioned, you need to put `format` into the options of the transport.
2. in order to build the plugin by yourself, you should use `symbol` type as the key instead of string:

   ```js
   info[Symbol.for('message')] = `!${info.message}!`;
   ```